# What kind of license is Redis' RSAL (Redis Source Available License)?

Tags: licensing, proprietary-code, open-source-definition, free-software-definition, cloud

The name would suggest it's not FOSS, but source available, which is a pretty low bar.

But when I read about it, they seem to suggest that it's really only source available for specific use cases being monetized by Redis Labs.

So, technically speaking, what's the right classification for RSAL?

Answer (score 6):

While there is a kind of classification for open-source licenses, the classifications don't really extend beyond open-source.

The best classification that I can come up with for the RSAL is that it is a source-available license that allows usages that don't compete with Redis Lab's business. But that classification of course only contains the one license.

Comment: "While there is a kind of classification for open-source licenses, the classifications don't really extend beyond open-source." – Indeed. For the purposes of classifying open source licenses, the classification of RSAL is simply "proprietary" or "not open source".